# Como formatar exibição de API REST em browser usando PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, acentuação

Estou montando uma API Rest usando PHP.

Os dados estão acentuados corretamente do banco de dados e chegam na aplicação também corretos. O problema está ao tentar acessar o endereço da API pelo browser. Quero que os dados, ao acessar pelo browser, combinem acentuação correta e indentação.

Se eu uso:

```
echo json_encode(
    $result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
);
```

os dados são mostrados indentados, mas a acentuação é exibida errada (unicode).

Se eu uso:

```
echo json_encode(
    $result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

os dados são exibidos com a acentuação correta, mas a indentação não existe (os dados ficam todos em uma linha contínua, dificultando a leitura).

Observações:

- O arquivo php está formatado em utf-8 no salvamento.
- O banco de dados é MySQL e está formatado também para utf-8.
- Tentei usar `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` e `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` no arquivo PHP sem sucesso.
- O charset padrão do servidor é UTF-8, de acordo com o phpinfo.

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual o servidor Web que você está usando? Pode ser que no servidor não esteja configurado como UTF-8 corretamente. O item header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' é realmente obrigatório.

Comment: @exp o phpinfo mostra que o charset padrão do servidor é utf-8.

Comment: Se usar como indica a doc não atende? Ex. json_encode($input,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Estava com um problema parecido no TCC, mesmo configurando tudo com utf-8, ao fazer uma select, colocava uns losangos preto no lugar das letras especiais, o que resolveu meu problema foi dar essas query antes de fazer a select: mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');